# Asyncronously Load Panels using jQuery in ASP.NET application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asynchronous, highcharts

I have an ASP.net application which contains a dashboard interface which consists of various number of panels. Each Panel contains a HighChart control and is loaded from a different data source. Some of the data source may take some time to execute, therefore I don't want to slow down the overall page execution because of one slow loading data source.

I would like the page to load then each panel to appear when it's data is ready.

As I'm using High charts to display the data I have jQuery code similar to:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var panelIDList = dashID.Get("panelList");

        for (var i = 0; i < panelIDList.length; i++) {
            addpanel(panelIDList[i]);
        }            
    }); 

    function addpanel(panelID)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Data.aspx/GetData",
            data: "{val:'" + panelID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                var myObject = eval('(' + msg.d + ')');

                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: myObject.renderTo,
                        type: myObject.chartVal,
                        height: 300,
                        width: 600
                    },
                xAxis: {
                        categories: myObject.xaxis.Categories,
                },
                series: myObject.serList
            };

            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        }
    });
```

As can be seen in $(document).ready I make an Ajax call back to the server to retrieve a JSON data structure which is used to construct the charts data.

This all works fine, except that the calls not seems to be truly asynchronous, if the first panel is slow to load then the subsequent panels aren't loaded until after the slow first panel loads. To demonstrate I've added a Thread.Sleep in 1 of the panels DataSource.

I wouldn't have though that this was the case as I'm using Ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

Well once I had a similar problem

First try adding

```
async: true,
cache: false
```

to you `ajax` call

If that doesn't solve your problem then you need to disable the `Session` on the page

```
<%@ Page EnableSessionState="False" ....
```

For more info:

[How to display the Asynchronous results which one is first in asp.netweb application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11080860/1268570)

[REST WCF service locks thread when called using AJAX in an ASP.Net site](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11250109/1268570)

Comment: Unfortunately I having the Session enabled on my page is pretty crucial to me application.  Setting async to true and cache to false doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Well then probably you should consider moving your PageMethods to services: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11250109/1268570, I just tested the solution provided in the previous link and it worked, even when the Session is enabled on the page

Comment: The problem I have is that I'm using Session information quite a bit, when a user logs on there is quite a bit of information stored in the session for that user, changes they make while in my app are also stored in the session.  It may be that I need to restructure my calls to pass all pertinent information as a WS call

Comment: Are you using your `Session` in the `GetData` method?

Comment: Yes, it's a dashboard type app. In the UI a user may change a whole host of parameter values, there will be other values set in the session based on their login (department, roles, access levels etc). This stuff must be persisted in the Session.  I could in theory pass all this information to the GetData method, however this could become very convuleted.

Comment: The problem is that ASP.Net blocks the requests using the `Session`. Have you tried [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)? maybe it fits your needs although at first sight I think it's an overhead to your problem

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Thanks for your help