# Load a Specific section first in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

The right panel in the page which is full of banners need to load before or side-by-side the left panel. The problem is that left panel is full of data and it's taking so much time to load so the right panel never show up before the left panel loading completes. Can somesone tell me how to load the right panel first or side by side??

Comment: See the link below perhaps it can help you

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645582/asyncronously-load-panels-using-jquery-in-asp-net-application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645582/asyncronously-load-panels-using-jquery-in-asp-net-application

Comment: I don't get it. How can <%@ Page EnableSessionState="False" %> solve my problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the jQuery load() function and have your panels in external aspx files:

http://api.jquery.com/load

This technique would load the panels at approximately the same time.

I am assuming that you don't have any server-side event handling in your panels...

Comment: @Steave Can you please explain how can I use load because both my panels are made from repeaters server side and I don't understand how to use load at client side because the panel is still not loaded.